# Why does .equals() result in an Assertion Error when comparing two objects...but only sometimes?

Tags: java, postgresql, unit-testing

I'm working on unit testing for a project at code school and `.equals()` is giving me some trouble. In my project, `.save()` is saving into an SQL database. This code passes the unit test:

```
@Test
public void save_assignsNameToObject() {
  Restaurant testRestaurant = new Restaurant("PokPok","503-444-4444");
  testRestaurant.save();
  Restaurant savedRestaurant = Restaurant.all.get(0);
  assertEquals(savedRestaurant.getName(), "PokPok");
}
```

But if I change the final line to the following, it will result in an assertion error:

```
assertTrue(savedRestaurant.equals(testRestaurant));
```

I debugged using `System.out.println()` to verify that both values in `testRestaurant` do ".equal" the corresponding values in `savedRestaurant`. The following unit test (for an object of another, very similar class) passes using the `.equals()` method:

```
@Test
public void save_assignsIdToObject_true() {
  Cuisine testCuisine = new Cuisine("Mexican");
  testCuisine.save();
  Cuisine savedCuisine = Cuisine.all().get(0);
  assertTrue(savedCuisine.equals(testCuisine));
}
```

Edit: here is my source code for `.equals()`:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object otherRestaurant) {
  if (!(otherRestaurant instanceof Restaurant)) {
    return false;
  } else {
    Restaurant newRestaurant = (Restaurant) otherRestaurant;
    return this.getId() == new Restaurant.getId() &&
           this.getName().equals(newRestaurant.getName()) &&
           ...
           this.getPhone().equals(newRestaurant.getPhone());
    }
  }
```

Why can `.equals()` compare some objects and not others? In my code example, the only difference I'm seeing is that one object takes one parameter, and the other takes two.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you should show us your overridden `equals` method for `Restaurant` class.

Comment: Can you show us `Cuisine` class?

Comment: @HollaHexkey refer my updated answer.

Comment: Are you suer it reads `this.getId() == new Restaurant.getId()`? Surely it should be `this.getId() == newRestaurant.getId()`. BTW - how are the IDs assigned?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon you're right! I mistyped here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `equals()` on a java object checks that they are the exact same object (not two objects with the same values). http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29

The String object overrides `equals()` to give a version which will return true for two different objects with the same value, but your custom `Restaurant` class does not.

You could define a custom `equals()` e.g.

```
public class Restaurant {

  private String name;
  private String tel;

  public Restaurant(String name, String tel) {
    this.name = name;
    this.tel = tel;
  }

  /*getters and setters*/

  override public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj instanceOf Restaurant) {
      Restaurant that = (Restaurant) obj;
      return (this.name.equals(that.getName()) && this.tel.equals(that.getTel()));
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Even with an overridden equals() for Restaurant, the above code still results in an assertion error. Is there something I should change in my assertion? I declare the variables and reference the objects in my constructor like in your example.

Comment: Downvoted for not implementing hashCode in your example.

Answer (score 1):

First compares `Strings` (`savedRestaurant.getName()`) where as second compares Objects of class `Restaurant` (`savedRestaurant`).

String has its own implementation of [equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

You need to override `equals` method in `Restaurant` to make equals work as you expect otherwise it will check if both the objects exact same or not ([object.equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)).

---

**Update:**

You have problem with this line in your equals method

if id is `long`

```
this.getId() == newRestaurant.getId() // not new Restaurant.getId()
```

if id is `Long`

```
this.getId().equals(newRestaurant.getId()) // not new Restaurant.getId()
```

Comment: Op ask why assertTrue(savedRestaurant.equals(testRestaurant)); doesnt work and assertTrue(savedCuisine.equals(testCuisine)); work

Comment: @ErwanC., I see. I have asked OP to show `Cuisine` class.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I neglected to mention my equals() override before (fixed). Cuisine class is quite long. It's formatted exactly like in @mattinbits 's code above though. Does that help?

Comment: You should debug your code and dig into your equals method and find out which condition is returning false. That will help to investigate your problem.

Answer (score 1):

By default your `Restaurant.equals()` falls back on `Object.equals()` which just compares the object identifiers. You are apparently getting back a different instance of `Restaurant` when you call `Restaurant.all.get(0)`. The field values are the same, but it's a different object instance.

I do not advise to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` because this is quite hard to get right and not needed here. I would just give each class an ID field, commonly a `long` value which maps to an auto-increment field in the database. The ID uniquely identifies each record in the database. Then in your test you can simply check if you got the object with the same database ID.

The reason why the behavior is currently different for `Cuisine` and `Restaurant` probably lies in code you didn't show us. Maybe they use different implementations of `equals()`? Or the way they are saved and retrieved work differently? Maybe `Cuisine.get()` returns the same object instance as that was saved and `Restaurant.get()` creates a new instance? For us to know you'd have to show the code of both classes.

Are you using an in-memory database for this? How are you storing `Restaurant` and `Cuisine` data?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Cuisine and Restaurant work almost identically and have almost identical code (including equals), with the one exception that Restaurant pulls in a cuisineID from the database according to the cuisine category that it falls into.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the implementation of *equals* in your *Restaurant* Class to be able to use it with proper sense to compare objects of that Class

The default equals comparison will lead you to the method in *Object* Class, which only check's if both objects point to same reference (same address in memory)

Comment: Try to avoid overriding equals(), but if you do you also have to override hashCode()

Comment: @AdriaanKoster, you are right, that we should overrid `hashCode()` also when we override `equals()`, but this problem of OP has nothing to do with `hashCode()` method.

Comment: It's a common source of nasty bugs so it cannot be left unmentioned.